# MS Access dialog box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created an access dialog box which gives my users to select a csv file, now I need to create another Import button which on click would pick the csv file selected in the dialog box and import it into my access table.

Below is the code which I used which allows my user to pick a csv file.

[VBA Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWDMw.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `.TransferText` method:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "table1", Me!Text165, True
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you @Applecore